# Generate a JavaFX application for mobile, with Eclipse + Gluon

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, javafx, gluon

I have some problem for running a JavaFX application on mobile (ex: Archos Diamond S with Android 5.1)

First of all, I have created a simple "Hello world" JavaFX application on Eclipse (SDK Mars.2 - 4.5.2).

Then, for generating an Android application whereas my source language is JavaFX, I have installed Gluon (with its JavaFXports) on Eclipse.
And, now, in Eclipse, there is the "Gradle tasks" tab. Fine!

Moreover, I have connected my mobile to my desktop through the USB port. My PC recognizes it (a popUp is automatically displayed with the mobile name and some mobile options as: "Synchronize ..", "import..", ....

Now, last step to do (I hope), when I launch the Gradle task "AndroidInstall", it seems to be that my mobile should display the generated Android application. But nothing appears on my mobile.

I have searched a file *.apk in my desktop, without success.

Note that when I choose "Run" as a Gradle task, my application works fine on my PC.

Have you an idea about this problem PC-mobile?

Thank you for your response

Comment: Have you enabled Developer Options on your phone? When running `androidInstall` see the output and check if it ends successfully. The apk will be under your project `/build/javafxports/android`. Otherwise, post the errors you find.

Comment: In Eclipse, on "AndroidInstall" task, there is no error log. Yes, I have the Developer options on my phone. But, I have not tried yet the security parameters about accepting the application install in case of unknown source. Is it useful, here?

Comment: Did you find the apk? If it is no there, the task wasn't successful.

Comment: Perhaps the reason of this problem  is the Java8 use whereas I should apply the "Retrolambda plugin to Java6 or 7"?

Comment: The apk will be under your project folder, `/build/javafxports/android`. If it is not there the build wasn't successful. Go to command line, to the project, and run `./gradlew --info androidInstall`. See if there is any exception, and edit your question and post it.

Comment: The solution is to install the API21 (platform android-21), in AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21 before launching the ""androidInstall" " gradle task:
That works fine. I have the two .apk files. Thanks!

Comment: But, "androidInstall" does not automatically launch this application on my mobile. I do copy my application.apk on it, then install it and launch it. An idea to directly and automatically drive my mobile with my PC without doing this manual process?

Comment: Probably you haven't authorized your mobile. In Settings->Developer Options-> enable USB debugging. In Settings->Security> enable unknown sources. Unplug your phone, plug it again, and on command line go to the android sdk folder->platform tools and type `adb logcat`. See if you can see the phone output on your console.

Comment: José, it does not matter BUT, in the gluon project, I must copy pictures in ios, android and desktop resources. Morevover, I have to change Java code to reach them.Neverthless,     I'm very happy to use the Java code with JavaFX APIs that I have tested before in Eclipse without Gluon, before. That shows that JavaFxports works fine in Gluon. Super! Now, I think that my mobile game with their 30 000 Java lines will work quickly. The "only" things to do will be: adapt the code in case of bad behavior on mobile, and modify the scale of objects (responsive action)

Comment: Can you create a new question on that changes, posting some screenshots of your project in Eclipse?

Comment: I have installed all Javafx and android tools on Eclipse Neon 2. That works better. So, this question is closed